# Removing part of a line? [bash]

Tags: bash, shell, sed, ps

I'm writing my own ps-command in bash, but i'm having some trouble getting cmdline. This is my code:

```
get_cmdline(){
if [ -f "/proc/$1/cmdline" ]; then
cat /proc/$1/cmdline | cut -d " " -f 1
else echo n/a
fi
}
```

But this is what i'm getting:

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox/opt/google/chrome/chrome--type=zygote
```

What is the easiest way to remove '--type=zygote'?

PS: I don't know command sed, so if used, I would greatly appreciate a detailed explanation

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using awk:

```
echo "/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox/opt/google/chrome/chrome--type=zygote" | awk -F "--" '{print $1}'
/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox/opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

awk will delimit the record on '--'. then i am printing field one only 1st field

using sed:

```
echo "/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox/opt/google/chrome/chrome--type=zygote" | sed 's/--.*//g'
/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox/opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

using pattern matching:

```
a="/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox/opt/google/chrome/chrome--type=zygote" 
echo ${a%--*}
/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox/opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

Comment: Please note that while this is the "easiest way to remove '--type=zygote'", it is not the cleanest nor most correct way.  In particular, look out for path or command names or flags that include '--' in them.  Text parsing in this problem is susceptible to being insecure or erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

inputs to `cut` need some reformatting. Use

```
cat /proc/$1/cmdline | cut -d\  -f 1
```

Mind ya, there is a space after the backslash.

BTW I see you asked "What is the easiest way to remove '--type=zygote'?" That is a different question, and are you looking for some `sed`-like thing?

Answer (score 1):

That should do it using sed:

```
$ echo "/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox/opt/google/chrome/chrome--type=zygote" | sed "s/--type.*$//"
/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox/opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

If you would like to use cut then:

```
$ echo "/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox/opt/google/chrome/chrome--type" | rev | cut -d'-' -f3- | rev
/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox/opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove exactly '--type=zygote' as you said in your post, you should use `sed` like this:

```
cat /proc/$1/cmdline | cut -d " " -f 1 | sed 's/--type=zygote//'
```

The command to `sed` is specified in the single quotes. `s` is the substitution command, its format is: `s/oldstuff/newstuff/` to substitute `oldstuff` with `newstuff`; if `newstuff` is empty line, the result is `oldstuff` being removed (you effectively substitute `oldstuff` with the empty line), which is what we do in our example.

If you want more universal action, e.g. removing the rest of the line starting with `--`, you should do:

```
cat /proc/$1/cmdline | cut -d " " -f 1 | sed 's/--.*//'
```

The only difference to the previous example here is that we use regular expression where `.` stands for "any symbol" and `*` specified any number of the preceding symbol, so `.*` means "any number of any symbols" and `--.*` means "-- followed by any number of any symbols".

`sed` is pretty powerful tool (and fun too!) so might want to take some time to read up on it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`/proc/*/cmdline` has commands and arguments separated by nulls.  You could use `sed` to remove everything after the first null:

```
sed 's/\x00.*//' < /proc/$1/cmdline
```

Or you could use `xargs` to reformat the nulls into spaces, then use `cut` or `sed` or `awk`:

```
xargs -0 echo < /proc/$1/cmdline | cut -d" " -f1
xargs -0 echo < /proc/$1/cmdline | sed 's/ .*//'
xargs -0 echo < /proc/$1/cmdline | awk '{print $1}'
```

(I'm not using `cat` to print out the `cmdline` files because that's unnecessary process activation; you can just use redirects to get info from a file into your command.)

Or even better, for a pure Bash solution, use `read` with a nil delimiter:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' foo < /proc/$1/cmdline
printf '%s\n' "$foo"
```

Note that `/proc` is not available everywhere.  (I don't know how to get command line information otherwise, though.)

Comment: I think the IFS setting is superfluous?